How to determine the sign of a 2x2 matrix eigen vector?
I am a junior student currently working on matrix eigen values and eigen vectors. I am indeed able to find the right values, BUT I sometimes write an eigen vector as positive when it is in fact negative and vice versa. Here is how I proceed:
Matrix A
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 2 & -12 \\ \hline 2 & -8 \\ \hline  \end{array}
Using the trace method, I determine that the eigen values of this matrix equal -2 and -4.
Then, I take A and subtract from it the identity matrix of A where I've inserted my eigen values (the process is repeated for each eigen value). For the first eigen value (-2), it gives:
(A - 1I) x_1 = 0

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 4 & -12 \\ \hline 2 & -6 \\ \hline  \end{array}times\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline x \\ \hline y \\ \hline  \end{array}
equals\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 0 \\ \hline 0 \\ \hline  \end{array}
Which leads me to produce the following:
4x+12y=0, 2x+6y=0

Then, I reduce the equations:
2x+3y=0, 1x+3y=0

There, I know that the first value of my eigen vector is 3. However, 3 expressed the reduction of -12 and -6. This leads me to think that the sign of 3 should be negative, in such a way that my eigen vector would be:
 [-3,1]
However, when I double check on an automated software, I get 3 and not -3. I am sure that I am missing something very basic but I can't spot what. If someone could help me out, I would be grateful.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

To expand what @YvesDaoust has said. There is no such thing as "the" eigenvector. If a vector $v$ is an eigenvector, so is every multiple $av$.  You are mistaken when you say that you know that the first coordinate is $3$; it might be $23$, and then the second coordinate is $-\frac{23}{3}$.

Hello. Thank you for the comments. Afntu, thank you. Will look into the links you shared with me. Under a lot of pressure rn. @ancientmathematician, yes, I understand that there isn't the one and only eigen vector of a matrix. I meant "the" as in "the first vector coordinate I obtain by applying the method I was taught". Yet, the eigen vector coordinates syst. match the coordinates of wolframalpha.com's eigen values and vectors calculator, bar for the sign of said coordinates (sometimes neg., sometimes pos). So, bottom line is that eigen vector coordinates aren't signed, correct?

Bottom line is not that eigenvector/eigenvector coordinates aren't signed, but that they are not scaled.: only the ratios are determined.
